# How to conditionally accumulate a pandas row with daily reset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas `df` looking like this:

```
                    price  quantity initiator
time                                          
2016-07-13 16:19:31   6.20      8000         B
2016-07-13 16:19:45   6.19      5176         S
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24     15000         NaN
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      2847         S
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24     39829         B
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      2398         B
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      1844         NaN
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      9538         S
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24       459         B
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      1082         B
```

I want to add a column with accumulated quantity, which starts at zero every day. The condition is if initiator is B then the quantity is positive, if S it is negative and if NaN it does not count.

So with the above data my new column would look like:

```
acc_quantity
8000
2824
2824
337
40166
42564
42564
33026
33485
34567
```

How would you conceptually do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `np.where` and `notnull` to create series of `[-1, 0, 1]`s.  Multiply this series by `df.quantity` and use `cumsum`.

We'll build a function to do the above and apply it in a `groupby` where we group by days.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

text = """time       price  quantity  initiator
2016-07-13 16:19:31   6.20      8000         B
2016-07-13 16:19:45   6.19      5176         S
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24     15000         NaN
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      2847         S
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24     39829         B
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      2398         B
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      1844         NaN
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      9538         S
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24       459         B
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      1082         B
2016-07-14 16:19:31   6.20      8000         B
2016-07-14 16:19:45   6.19      5176         S
2016-07-14 16:25:08   6.24     15000         NaN
2016-07-14 16:25:08   6.24      2847         S
2016-07-14 16:25:08   6.24     39829         B
2016-07-14 16:25:08   6.24      2398         B
2016-07-14 16:25:08   6.24      1844         NaN
2016-07-14 16:25:08   6.24      9538         S
2016-07-14 16:25:08   6.24       459         B
2016-07-14 16:25:08   6.24      1082         B"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])

def accumulator(df):
    initiator = np.where(df.initiator == 'B', 1, -1) * df.initiator.notnull()
    return pd.DataFrame((df.quantity * initiator).cumsum(), df.index, ['acc_quantity'])

pd.concat([df, df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).apply(accumulator)], axis=1)
```

**Notice** The values reset at the start of the new day.

[image]

Comment: That works great, cheers. How about resetting the acc_quantity to zero every day, any thoughts?

Comment: @cJc Updated post.

Comment: Nicely done! I forgot to mention that my data comes in the form of a pandas data frame, using pandas to import the file in the first place. I'm not familiar with StringIO and I get an error message when I run the code on a df instead of a text string like you use in your example. How do I get around this?

Comment: @cJc `StringIO` mimics  a file.  When I read the text, I make a lot of decisions with the `pd.read_csv` function.  `sep='\s{2,}'` says to to treat 2 or more whitespace characters as a column delimeter.  `index_col=0` says the first column is the index.  `parse_dates=[0]` says the first column should also be parsed as a datetime/timestamp.  Most likely the error you are seeing is due to a difference in the file format and failure to parse in the manner I've done.  Or you aren't replicating the same parameters I've used.

Comment: I guess the difference in file format. Can I use StringIO with data frames or do I have to solve it in a different way?

Comment: You use `StringIO` with a string.  It allows me to use the text pasted to SO as if it were a file.  It often presents inconsistencies between OP (you) and answerers (me) which lead to lingering questions like "why doesn't it work for me".  Its always best to present your sample data in the form of code that can reproduce it.  That way, you can verify that the data produced does in fact result in the problem you are facing.  And, we can clearly see what the problem is and don't have to spend more time figuring out if you parsed dates correctly.  This isn't always possible though.

Comment: I appreciate all your help! I did however state in the very first line of my question that my data is in a pandas df. The data is on my harddisk and not sure how I could share this file with you. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad I could help.  Hopefully you get that last bit figured out.